# How to unlock file, locked by a process

Tags: java, lock, lsof

The file is locked by a process, java in my case. I only want the lock to be released.

```
lsof | grep /home/user/workspace1
```

[image: lsof]

A temporary solution was to 'End Process' from 'System Monitor'. 
[image: End Process] 
But terminating java(Java Virtual Machine) would terminate all other programs using java. So how shall I release the lock held by any process. For the same purpose Windows has an application called 'Unlocker'.

Answer (score 0):

Try [lockf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html).

> lockf - apply, test or remove a POSIX lock on an open file
>
> The lockf() function allows sections of a file to be locked with
>   advisory-mode locks. Calls to lockf() from other processes which
>   attempt to lock the locked file section will either return an error
>   value or block until the section becomes unlocked. All the locks for a
>   process are removed when the process terminates. Record locking with
>   lockf() is supported for regular files.<sup>[IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.bpxbd00/rlockf.htm)</sup>

Comment: This is a C function, not a program. Not sure how it will help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure this will work on your particular lockfiles but [`lock-remove`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/lockfile-remove.1.html) might be worth a try:

```
lockfile-remove [--lock-name] filename

DESCRIPTION
   Lockfile-progs provides a set a programs that can be used to  lock  and
   unlock mailboxes and files safely (via liblockfile):
```

So, try something like

```
lockfile-remove /home/user/workspace1/.metadata/.lock
```

Another, more brutal approach, is to simply delete the lockfile.